# how can i echo only once in while loop in php and csv

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a simple query script of a csv file in PHP.
this is my script:

```
<?php
$query = trim($_POST['query']);

echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$result = false;

while (($row = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {


if ($row[0] == $query){
echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $cell) {


                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";


}
if (empty($cell)){
    echo "nothing";
}
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

My data.csv file is:
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1

my output if result is found:

```
nothing
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
foo,bar,1
```

my output if no results are found:

```
nothingnothingnothingnothingnothing
```

what am I doing wrong, and how can i fix it so it would the correct output if a result was fount and if nothing was found.

Comment: I think it'll work a lot better if you replaced `if (empty($cell))` by `else`. The 'else' is used for the case that nothing was found. Of course you would need to make `echo "nothing";` into a table row as well.

Comment: I tried that the the output is the same for `else` as for if `(empty($cell))`